# Multiple not() DOM Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, selector

I want to select a particular node with two not clauses, but I had no success so far. What I need to do is, select an element whose div contains the string 0008, but it's not 10008 and also it does **not** contain the tag "style", so, in theory it should work like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll(" div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008'][style])")
```

However, as you might suspect, it doesn't work that way.

```
document.querySelectorAll(" div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008'])")
document.querySelectorAll(" div[id*='0008']:not([style])")
```

Both of them work perfectly individually, of course.

Comment: Did you try `$(" div[id*='0008']:not([style]):not([id='10008'])")`

Comment: This is the expected behavior of `querySelectorAll`. Complex selectors are not allowed in a `:not()`. The solution proposed by @adeneo should work.

Comment: If you combine them, it's saying NOT elements that have both, but allow elements that have one or the other.

Comment: @KevinB: If you combine them, it throws a DOM Exception.

Comment: My point wasn't whether or not it is syntactically correct, it's logically wrong regardless of whether or not it is valid syntax.

Comment: Logic is irrelevant if the code doesn't run.

Comment: Is this a jQuery question?  Or a `document.querySelectorAll()` question? There are different options open for each.

Answer (score 11):

> not 10008 and also it does not …

That's not what your current selector checks, it test whether it has not ( the id and a style attribute ) . Use this instead:

```
div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008']):not([style])
```

Your original solution also was not a valid selector, since [`:not()` may only contain one *simple selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation), while you had two of them. Yet, selector libraries like jQuery's sizzle engine might [support them](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). So with jQuery, the following would work as well:

```
div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008'],[style])
```

Comment: div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008']):not([style]) Worked beautifully, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/NBMeQ/)

Logically, you are trying to exclude elements that match either of the two undesired selectors, not elements that match them both. In jQuery, the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (which will then match all of the undesired elements, then be negated) is simply a comma-separated listing. Therefore you simply do this:

```
$("div[id*='0008']:not([id='10008'],[style])")
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) (since this question is tagged jQuery):

> All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do:

```
var elems = $('div[id*="0008"]').filter(function() {
    return !this.hasAttribute("style") && this.id == '10008';
});
```

I don't think I really get this, but this would filter out:

```
<div id="10008" style="color: black">10008</div>
```

but not:

```
<div id="10008">10008</div>
```

ID's are of course unique, and there could be a real world use case for this, but it still seems like an edge case that you'd normally handle some other way, as once you'd filtered out the ID, why exactly do you need to match a style tag as well ?

Comment: Any reason for not using `!this.style`? (I'm genuinely curious, but not so much so that I've experimented at all...)

Comment: have'nt tested it, but I'm guessing `this.style` contains all and any styles, and I think the point was to check for the actual attribute, hence `hasAttribute()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes. The `style` property always contains a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which is truthy - even if there are no inline styles set.